# Anonymous Delegate - Search property with collection of objects

Tags: c#, anonymous-methods

Here is the current code in my application using an anonymous delegate to search a collection on properties:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject() { }

    public string MyObjectId { get; set; }
    public List<MySubObject> SubObjects { get; set; }
}

public class MySubObject
{
    public MySubObject() { }

    public string MySubObjectId { get; set; }
}

public List<MyObject> Search(string input)
{
    List<MyObject> AllObjects = Data.GetAllObjects();
    List<MyObject> SearchResults = new List<MyObject>();

    SearchResults = AllObjects.FindAll
    (
        delegate(MyObject o)
        {
            return e.MyObjectId.Equals(input)
        }
    );

    if (SearchResults .Count.Equals(0))
            SearchResults = null;

        return SearchResults ;
}
```

I want to modify the anonymous delegate to search by the `MySubObject.MySubObjectId` property in the generic list instead of the `MyObjectId` property.  How would I modify the code in the anonymous delegate to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
delegate(MyObject o) {
  var mySubObject = o as MySubObject;
  return mySubObject != null && mySubObject.MySubObjectId == input;
}
```

Note that you could also use shorter lambda syntax here

```
(o) => {
  var mySubObject = o as MySubObject;
  return mySubObject != null && mySubObject.MySubObjectId == input;
}
```

Or a LINQ query

```
var searchResult = AllObjects
  .OfType<MySubObject>()
  .Where(x => x.MySubObjectId == input)
  .Cast<MyObject>()
  .ToList()
```

Comment: I still want to keep it as an `MyObject` data type but search the on the `SubObjects` properties of the `MyObject` object

Comment: @MichaelKniskern fixed it so searchResult is still `List<MyObject>` in the LINQ case

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using lambda expressions. Basically an object is found if at least one of its subobjects contains the required input.

```
SearchResults = AllObjects.Where(obj => 
    obj.SubObjects != null 
    && obj.SubObjects.Any(subObj => ubObj.MySubObjectId.Equals(input))
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it could be trimmed down a lot, but you need to get rid of `null` assignments to the lists:

```
public List<MyObject> Search(string input)
{
    return Data.GetAllObjects()
        .Where(obj => obj.SubObjects
            .Any(subobj => subobj.SubOjectId.Equals(input)));
}
```

`.Clear()` your lists instead of nullifying them, for a more consistent design and a lot less null-checking.